# Different notations for synchronous and asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Do you ever thought about using different naming notations to separate synchronous code from asynchronous in your code? Like

```
function i_am_synchronous()
{
   return 1;
}

function iAmAsynchronous(callback)
{
   db.query("SELECT * FROM 'table",callback)
}
```

Is it a good or a bad idea? What do you think?

Comment: I think a suffix is the most used method of marking a method as synchroneous or not. Generally speaking, the callback parameter or the promise result gives it away though.

Comment: as per @Tibos comment you should use, `sync_myFunction` and `async_otherFunction`.

Comment: In NodeJS, suffixes are commonly used: `fs.writeFile` (asynchronous) and `fs.writeFileSync` (synchronous, duh)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is bad idea to use synchronous calls in javascript at all, avoid this. To get something like simulation of synchronous calls I recommend to use Deferred objects (for example http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Also i recommend everywhere where u need some I/O or remote server calls to make it possible to use both callbacks and Deferred objects like it was done in jQuery.ajax function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . Here u can do in  callbacks way or in Deferred way and it is absolutely pure for the client which uses this ajax call

Comment: Your first statement is too strict. `var result = Math.round(1.234);` - This is also a synchronous call. Or would you rather have `FictiveAsyncMath.round(1.234, function(result) { });` ?

Comment: i mean 'I/O or remote server calls'

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious from the function signature and/or its description how it operates. If you pass a callback to the function which is executed *after* the function does something, that pretty much means it's asynchronous. It would not make much sense to use such callbacks with synchronous functions. The exception is something like `.sort()`, but its purpose and mode of operation is very different and the purpose of its callback is different.

In short: you (hopefully) don't call functions without knowing what they do and what their arguments and return values represent. From this you already know whether the function operates synchronously or asynchronously, you don't need additional syntax to signal that.